# Convert "General" data type to Date

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, sage-erp

This might be a simple question, but I couldn't find a solution. I have an Excel Spreadsheet with a PostDate column whose value is: `VLOOKUP(E2,upload!A:H,2,FALSE)` and it shows as a Date. I'm using this spreadsheet as a data source, but my application (Sage MAS 500) sees the result of this calculation as a number, not a date and thus it fails to import the job.

For example, a PostDate in the spreadsheet shows 11/18/2013, but the preview data in the application shows 41596.

Is there a formula that I can use in the cells to convert this value to a Date? I tried using DATEVALUE, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DATEVALUE` function does the reverse - it converts a text string that looks like a date to a true date. To convert a date to text try `TEXT` function, e.g.

`=TEXT(VLOOKUP(E2,upload!A:H,2,FALSE),"m/d/yyyy")`

change the "m/d/yyyy" part to whatever date format you require

Comment: Perhaps I have this all wrong but I'm assuming that the application referred to will just read the date serial number - regardless of formatting?

Comment: + 1 I misunderstood the quesiton... the title and the last part confused me :)

Comment: @barry houdini: you assumed correctly. You answer solved my issue.